# Getting driving distance from openstreetmaps in R

Tags: r, routes, openstreetmap

For a project, I have to find driving distances of about 60,000 routes from a location (long-lat) to a location (long-lat). I currently use Google Maps via **ggmap** but the amount of requests per day is too low for my purposes. A friend suggested that OpenStreetMaps might be a solution.

Is there any way in R to either

1. download openstreetmaps and calculate the shortest/fastest route locally in my computer
2. ask http://openrouteservice.org/ or a similar server via a function similar to **ggmap**'s route()?
3. or some other way how to do it in R?

Many thanks,
Michal

Comment: I think [this site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) is more suitable for such question.

Comment: We would love to see R support implemented for the open source routing engine GraphHopper. Let me know if you need help :) !